# AttributeError: 'YouTubeTrack' object has no attribute 'tracks' when using wavelink library in nextcord bot

Tags: python, nextcord

I'm working on a music bot using the nextcord library and the wavelink library for audio streaming. When I execute the `/play <channel> <song_query>` command, it raises an `AttributeError` with the message "`'YouTubeTrack' object has no attribute 'tracks'`". How can I resolve this error and retrieve the tracks from the `search_result` object?

I expect the bot to play the song using wavelink.

This is my code and error message:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption
from nextcord.ext import commands
import os
import wavelink

intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.voice_states = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", intents=intents)

serverID = 993905332239741049 # Server ID

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Online")
    bot.loop.create_task(node_connect())

@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_node_ready(node: wavelink.Node):
    print(f"Node {node.id} is ready!")

async def node_connect():
    node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri='lavalink.devamop.in', password='DevamOP')
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=bot, nodes=[node])

@bot.slash_command(description="Play a song", guild_ids=[serverID])
async def play(interaction: Interaction, channel: nextcord.VoiceChannel = SlashOption(description="Voice channel to join."), search: str = SlashOption(description="Song name.")):
    vc: wavelink.Player = await channel.connect(cls=nextcord.VoiceClient)
    search_result = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search, return_first=True)  # Retrieve search result
    if search_result:
        track = search_result.tracks[0]  # Retrieve the first track from the search result
        await vc.play(track)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("No search results found.")

bot.run("BOT_TOKEN_HERE")
```

```
Bot is Online
Node mkEgybW39tS8 is ready!
Ignoring exception in command <nextcord.application_command.SlashApplicationCommand object at 0x00000213ED9E17E0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Teh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 890, in invoke_callback_with_hooks
    await self(interaction, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Teh\OneDrive\Desktop\heisenmusic\gustavo.py", line 34, in play
    track = search_result.tracks[0]  # Retrieve the first track from the search result
AttributeError: 'YouTubeTrack' object has no attribute 'tracks'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'YouTubeTrack' object has no attribute 'tracks'
```